# How do I add an audio player to my bootstrap navbar using Rails 3.2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, audio-streaming

I'm in the process of making a web app that scrapes music blogs for mp3 files and aggregates them in a single location (similar to http://hypem.com). I need to add an audio player to my website that will play multiple mp3 files from a database in the same player.

Ideally I would like to put this player in the navbar of my app so that it is always visible when the user is scrolling through the page. I am using the bootstrap gem with rails 3.2 for my styling and I was hoping to integrate the player directly into this framework.